# py4j - use the java member object in multiprocessing

Tags: java, python, multiprocessing, py4j

I have two java objects that take some input and return an output. To make them available in Python I start a JVM using
`subprocess.popen(java -Xmx3g -Xms3g -jar <fullpath\test.jar>)`

I then build a gateway using:

```
gateway = JavaGateway(
        gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=11001),
        callback_server_parameters=CallbackServerParameters(port=21001))

# load functions
modelCallCard = gateway.entry_point.modelCallCard
modelCallFlexi = gateway.entry_point.modelCallFlexi
```

The modelCallCard & modelCallFlexi are some java functions (I don't know much about those as I couldn't find them anywhere) that work fine if I don't use multiprocessing:

```
def modelCall(args):
    PRODUCT = args['PRODUCT']
    derivedVarsJson = args['derivedVarsJson']

    if PRODUCT.upper() == 'CARD':
        scoreInfoJson = modelCallCard(derivedVarsJson)
    else:
        scoreInfoJson = modelCallFlexi(derivedVarsJson)
    return scoreInfoJson

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(inputFileName, sep=dlm_out, encoding='utf-8', header=0, index_col='_index_', usecols=['_index_', 'ACC_ID', 'PRODUCT', 'derivedVarsJson'])

    df['_source_'] = df[['PRODUCT', 'derivedVarsJson']].to_dict(orient='records')
    df['scoreInfoJson'] = df['_source_'].map(modelCall)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to utilize multiprocessing and call the above function in parallel. For that I modified the function to:

```
def outer_func(args2):
    temp_df = args2[0]
    modelCallCard = args2[1]
    modelCallFlexi = args2[2]

    def modelCall(args):
        PRODUCT = args['PRODUCT']
        derivedVarsJson = args['derivedVarsJson']

        if PRODUCT.upper() == 'CARD':
            scoreInfoJson = modelCallCard(derivedVarsJson)
        else:
            scoreInfoJson = modelCallFlexi(derivedVarsJson)
        return scoreInfoJson

    temp_df['scoreInfoJson'] = temp_df['_source_'].map(modelCall)

    return temp_df
```

To call the modified function using multiprocessing, I made following changes:

```
def main():
    cpuCount = 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpuCount)
    reader = pd.read_csv(inputFileName, sep=dlm_out, encoding='utf-8', header=0, chunksize=chunkSize, index_col='_index_', usecols=['_index_', 'ACC_ID', 'PRODUCT', 'derivedVarsJson'])

    for c, df in enumerate(reader):
        logger.info(f'iterating ({c}) ...')

        df['_source_'] = df[['PRODUCT', 'derivedVarsJson']].to_dict(orient='records')

        dfs = np.array_split(df, cpuCount)
        args = [(dfs[i], modelCallCard, modelCallFlexi) for i in range(cpuCount)]

        dfResults = pool.map(outer_func, args)
        df = pd.concat(dfResults)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But this code throws an error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling t.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```